# How do I fix this RegExp problem with JavaScript Compiler Error in GTM?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

When trying to publish new GTM version I get errors with variables that I haven't edited (they used to work, and now they're showing errors).

> Error message:JavaScript Compiler Error Error at line 4, character 18:
>   Cannot convert ECMASCRIPT_2018 feature "RegExp Lookbehind" to targeted
>   output language.

Code:

```js
function(){

  var myRegexp = /(?<=(\/.*\/cat\/)).*?(?=\/)/g; //regex rule
  var result = document.URL.match(myRegexp);
  if(result !== null){
    return result[0];
  }else{
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: You must use a JavaScript transpiler somewhere. Which?

Comment: @yunzen, since this is a GTM post he is talking about Google Closure Compiler, which is what GTM used "behind the scenes" when it is preparing the JS file that contains all tags etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookbehind is a pretty new feature - only some browsers support it, and it can't exactly be transpiled (as far as I've seen), thus the error. Use standard matching instead of lookbehind, with a capturing group for the part after `cat/`, and return the first capturing group:

```
var pattern = /\/.*\/cat\/([^/]+)/;
var match = document.URL.match(pattern);
return match
? match[1]
: null;
```

Comment: The message appears in this code: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/640fd3f705dd5f015278abfd756b6a793ceecc73/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/MarkUntranspilableFeaturesAsRemoved.java#L46

Comment: @FilipKapusta The code there recently changed: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/commit/d2b7e5023ca5f330140e93d6a4ded89f1b6984e0 The lookbehind may have worked before, on modern browsers, but I bet it threw errors in older browsers like IE. Now, rather than throwing on IE, it's throwing in the build process, to prompt you to fix it earlier :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help in understanding and resolving this issue!